# Azure Blobs: Get Block List in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am working with [Block Blobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691964.aspx) in Azure Storage. I need to get uncommitted blocks, as far as I have found I need to call "Get Block List". Here is the problem.

Does "Get Block List" functionality exists in C# (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll)?

MSDN only says about doing a HTTP request, not a word about StorageClient API.

If this function does not exists in C#, are there any plans to include it to the C# API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the DownloadBlockList method on CloudBlockBlob
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblockblob.downloadblocklist.aspx

There's example code there in MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee772860.aspx

```
static void DownloadBlockListForBlob(Uri blobEndpoint, string accountName, string accountKey)
{
    //Create service client for credentialed access to the Blob service, using development storage.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(blobEndpoint, new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName, accountKey)); 

    //Get a reference to a block blob.
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobClient.GetBlockBlobReference("mycontainer/mybinaryblob.mp3");

    //Download the committed blocks in the block list.
    foreach (var blockListItem in blockBlob.DownloadBlockList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Block ID: " + blockListItem.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Block size: " + blockListItem.Size);
        Console.WriteLine("Is block committed?: " + blockListItem.Committed);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    //Download only uncommitted blocks.
    foreach (var blockListItem in blockBlob.DownloadBlockList(BlockListingFilter.Uncommitted))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Block ID: " + blockListItem.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Block size: " + blockListItem.Size);
        Console.WriteLine("Is block committed?: " + blockListItem.Committed);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    //Download all blocks.
    foreach (var blockListItem in blockBlob.DownloadBlockList(BlockListingFilter.All))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Block ID: " + blockListItem.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Block size: " + blockListItem.Size);
        Console.WriteLine("Is block committed?: " + blockListItem.Committed);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this is it. I have already tryed this method, but without a filter option. It is strange that the empty method does not return all blocks ... This confused me and I thought that uncommited block are not returned via this method. Thanks, that you point that out!

Comment: Your MSDN links are stale: "We're sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into GetBlockListResponse class in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Protocol namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758632.aspx

Hope this helps

Thanks

Gaurav